# Var not defined even tho it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

When I try to do `console.log(answers.slot1);` it gives me an error saying that `answers` is not defined. What is wrong with this?

**This is all my code. Function `handleDropEvent` is called from an HTML page which has nothing to do with the actual problem.**

```js
$(function() {
  const correct = [{
    slot: "slot1",
    item: "item3"
  }, {
    slot: "slot2",
    item: "item5"
  }, {
    slot: "slot3",
    item: "item2"
  }, {
    slot: "slot4",
    item: "item7"
  }, {
    slot: "slot5",
    item: "item7"
  }, {
    slot: "slot6",
    item: "item4"
  }];

  var answers = [{
    slot1: ""
  }, {
    slot2: ""
  }]

  function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
    var item = ui.draggable;
    var slot = $(this).attr('id');
    ui.draggable.position({ 
      of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    });

    console.log(answers.slot1);
  }
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">


<img src="image1.png">

<div id="slot1" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot2" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot3" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot4" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot5" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot6" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot7" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<div id="slot8" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>holder</p>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div id="item1" class="item item1 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item2" class="item item2 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item3" class="item item3 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item4" class="item item4 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item5" class="item item5 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item6" class="item item6 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item7" class="item item7 ui-widget-content">
</div>
<div id="item8" class="item item8 ui-widget-content">
</div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When is `handleDropEvent` called? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Because you get an error, and not 'undefined', this is most likely a scope issue. Could you please edit the question to include an example of your code which includes the scopes of all variables.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That is actually all my code, I'm not so experienced in js so I understand this may be dumb

Comment: If that's all of your code, where is the `handleDropEvent` function being called from, as @Ivar mentioned?

Comment: The error _"answers is not defined."_ is not possible because `answers` is always declared in the code. Even if its `undefined`  it will not throw the error you told.

Comment: @MaheerAli Well, that's why I'm asking https://gyazo.com/a9a4958fb36931201d226508990afa9b

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan from an html

Comment: And the code is...? Come on, we're trying to help you but you're not making it easy for us

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added that to the question, but that code just have nothing to do with the problem

Comment: `Function handleDropEvent is called from an HTML page which has nothing to do with the actual problem` It has everything to do with the problem. If you're calling the function from a HTML `on*` attribute then it has to be in global scope. HOWEVER your `answers` array is defined within the scope of a document.ready handler, so one cannot be called from the other. This is why we've asked you so many times to give us an *accurate* example of the JS as what you have will work, so this is clearly not what the code looks like in your page.

Comment: @gezuz "_from an html_". I don't see any mentioning of `handleDropEvent` from the HTML you provided either.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well I'm not calling it like that. Believe it or not this is all my code.  As you can see in the tags im using "JQuery".

Comment: @Ivar As I told Rory, **I'm using JQuery**

Comment: I can see that, the problem is that nothing you have shown calls the `handleDropEvent` function, so right now nothing will happen. Yet you state you're getting errors, so *something* is calling the function, but we cannot see what.

Comment: Just because 'you're using jQuery' doesn't mean things happen by magic. The code here is incomplete which is why we cannot help you. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually my function is being called and it is working the way I want except what I'm asking here.

Comment: @gezuz The brackets in the code you provided don't add up. So that code wont run at all right now. But even if I add some for the code to be runnable, [I'm not getting the error you mention](https://jsfiddle.net/0yp5xg3j/).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I literally copied and pasted all my code. You want the css too?

Comment: In that case there must be a file you're missing somewhere which hooks up the event handlers.

Comment: `answers` is an array use index to access to your object `answers[0]`

Answer (score 1):

`answers.slot1` will get the `slot1` property of array.You need to get the first element of array and then access its property

```js
var answers = [
    {slot1: ""},
    {slot2: ""}
]
console.log(answers[0].slot1)
```

Comment: while that is a (seperate) issue, what the OP has done should have logged *undefined* not thrown an error.

Comment: @gezuz what do you expect to be logged?

Comment: @MaheerAli Whatever I store in "slot1"

Comment: @gezuz Create a code snippet to show the problem. Your provided code is not enough to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `answers` is an array, not an object:

```
  var answers = [{
    slot1: ""
  }, {
    slot2: ""
  }]
```

So `console.log(answers.slot1);` would return `undefined` regardless.

For the above to work, you would need to iterate in the array first like:

```
console.log(answers[0].slot1); // Outputs ""
```

Perhaps you would be better to define an object if you want to keep the structure `answers.slot1` like so:

```
var answers = {
  slot1: "foo",
  slot2: "bar"
}

console.log(answers.slot1); // Outputs "foo"
```

**If you are accessing `answers` within a function**, make sure it is already defined before you call the function (as your code does not show when `handleDropEvent()` is called).

For example:

This would throw `answers is not defined`:

```
function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  console.log(answers)
}

handleDropEvent() // Outputs "answers is not defined"

var answers = {
  slot1: "foo",
  slot2: "bar"
}
```

At the time `handleDropEvent` is called, `answers` is not yet defined.

**Working example**:

```
function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
  console.log(answers.slot1)
}

var answers = {
  slot1: "foo",
  slot2: "bar"
}

handleDropEvent() // Outputs "foo"
```

As other users have pointed out, we cannot accurately debug your code as it is, as `handleDropEvent` which triggers the error is not being called in the code you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes, ```handleDropEvent``` is being called.

Comment: Thanks @gezuz, the code in your question defines the function - but at no point I can see the line `handleDropEvent(foo, bar)` which calls it. The issue will most likely be it is being called before the variable is defined (as above).

Comment: JQuery has an event when an element is dropped. The function is being called from that. I'll look into that, thanks